# Alamofire GET request parameters

Tags: swift, alamofire

When send GET request with parameters, url encoded in a different way

```
http://someurl/search-ads?attributes[elevator]=1&attributes[ranges][square][]=20.0&attributes[ranges][square][]=170.0&cities[]=somecity&currency=kgs&has_images=0&not_first_floor=1&not_last_floor=1&order_type=sale&rating__gte=5&rating__lte=10000&specialty=2
```

but it should be

```
http://someurl/search-ads?specialty=7&order_type=sale&attributes={"ranges":"{\"square\":[2450,8190]}"}&cities=somecity&page=1
```

Is there any settings to change, to force Alamofire to encode in second way?

I am using Alamofire 3

Here is my method

```
func makeSearch(search: GeneralSearch) {
        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, SearchURL, parameters: Mapper().toJSON(search), encoding: .URL).validate().responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let responseValue = response.result.value {
                    print(responseValue)
                }
                break
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is wrong. It wont be answered. The wrong side was our backend part. They wanted me to send params like url encoded with json as it's value. Not JSONString but JSON itself. At the moment of asking it, I didn't understood the absurdness of this question